# One of my variables is being printed but the other is not in tkinter Entry boxes

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I'm trying to create a function in tkinter where I can print out what the user writes in a `Entry` box. I'm able to print out `ask_an_entry_get`, but when I try to print `what_is_answer_entry_get`
, I get nothing my empty spaces.

Please find out the problem here. Also I'm using the `Entry` widget, along with the `get()` function, to get input from the user.

```
def answer_quizmaker_score():
    print(ask_an_entry_get)
    print(what_is_answer_entry_get)
```

I made a lot of global variables so I could use them all around my code.

```
global what_is_answer_entry    
what_is_answer_entry = Entry(root4)
what_is_answer_entry.pack()
```

I then used the `get()` function to retrieve what the user typed.

```
global what_is_answer_entry_get
what_is_answer_entry_get = what_is_answer_entry.get()
```

This is the exact process I did for both `ask_an_entry_get` and `what_is_answer_entry_get`. However for some reason only `ask_an_entry_get` is printed, while `what_is_answer_entry_get` is printing nothing in the console.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], There's currently isn't enough code in your question to answer it.

Comment: What matters is *when* or what conditions cause the `what_is_answer_entry.get()` to be executed — which is why you need to post a complete (or at least much more complete) example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

txt1 = StringVar()
txt2 = StringVar()

def txt_printer():
    print(txt1.get())
    print(txt2.get())

x = Entry(root, textvariable=txt1, width=20)
x.place(x=0, y=0)

y = Entry(root, textvariable=txt2, width=20)
y.place(x=0, y=50)

btn_print = Button(root, text="print", command=txt_printer)
btn_print.place(x=0, y=100)

# Or if you want to show the txt on window then:

def txt_on_window():
    lb1 = Label(root, text=txt1.get())
    lb1.place(x=0, y=200)
    lb2 = Label(root, text=txt2.get())
    lb2.place(x=0, y=235)

btn_print_on_window = Button(root, text="print on screen", command=txt_on_window)
btn_print_on_window.place(x=0, y=150)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to stack overflow I was not able to answer porperly...

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't helps.